# Arranging multiple regression results in python sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, coefficients

I have coefficients from running multiple regression.

I want to arrange the independent variables as column names, and then place coefficients as the first row, to be able to see which independent variable has which coefficient.

```
#assigning independent variables to x
x = df.drop("dependent var", axis = 1)
...
#creating a data frame with independent variables as headers
df_coef = pd.DataFrame(columns = x.columns)
#adding a row with a coefficients
df.loc[0] = x
#shifting index by 1
df.index = df.index + 1
#sorting by index 
df = df.sort()
```

I am getting an error:

```
ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In which line are you getting error? Also explain more about what you want to do. Show some data samples. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: My guess would be that `df.loc[0] = x` produces the error, since `x` a copy of the `df` itself without the "dependedn var" column(s) - thus the mismatch. As @VivekKumar said, more information is necessary for this.

Answer (score 0):

The first command line:

```
#assigning independent variables to x
x = df.drop("dependent var", axis = 1)
```

What you are doing here is copying your original dataframe, df, without the "dependent var" column. (it was, as suggested by the command, ***dropped*** from the dataframe)

Whatever columns are left at df are than being associated as headers to your new df:

```
#creating a data frame with independent variables as headers
df_coef = pd.DataFrame(columns = x.columns)
```

Afterwise, you try to add a row to your new df, at index position 0, with a single value:

```
#adding a row with a coefficients
df.loc[0] = x
```

This is most likely where your error occurs, the df most likely has more than one column, yet, you try to create a row with a singular value and hence get the error message:

```
ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns
```

You might be using an IDE to code, if so, a good advice is to use a more friendly data visualization tool, such as anaconda/jupyter notebook. With it you can visualize data step by step, which would help avoid the mistake done at the first step.

Hope that helps,